# How to get only the first column of this table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set the first column of tables, like the following, to be sticky dynamically; when there is no first column with a `rowspan` attribute it's ok, but when I get tables like this the `z-index` is overlaid by the last td:

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg th {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg .tg-0pky {
  border-color: inherit;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0pky" rowspan="3"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0pky" colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:first-child` and the `:last-child` selectors.

What we essentially do in the first part is choosing the first-child within the `tr` element. Then, we choose the first `td` element inside the first `tr` we selected.

In the second part, we choose the last-child within the `tr` element. Then, we choose the first `td` element inside the last `tr` we selected.

```css
tr:first-child > td:first-child  {
  background-color: red;
}

tr:last-child > td:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

> The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents the first element among a group of sibling elements.

> The :last-child CSS pseudo-class represents the last element among a group of sibling elements.

[first-child docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) | [last-child docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg th {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg .tg-0pky {
  border-color: inherit;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top
}

tr:first-child>td:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}

tr:last-child>td:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0pky" rowspan="3"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0pky" colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: i have updated the table on the question, if i implement your code on the new table only the first td of the first tr will be red, right?

Comment: @FernandoPiacezziFerreira You're right. I updated my answer with your updated table. What I don't understand is the dynamic behavior of your table. Therefore I'm not sure if this answer solves your question. It would be helpful if you could give some more context about the behavior (for example, the different states).

Comment: they are dynamically in the way i cant control how the table will came to me, so i need a css or js that works for every type of table. the tables are written by other people and i just control the styles and behavior, it's complicated, but your answer gives me a path. thanks

Comment: @FernandoPiacezziFerreira, Glad I could help. Good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the :first selector

for example with jquery

```
$("tr").each(function(){   console.log($("td:first", this)) })
```

But i am not sure what you mean becaues you tagged also html and css

with this selection you can add css dynamically.
without jquery its a little more code

```
tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
Array.from(tr).forEach((row) => console.log(row.children[0]) )
```

Comment: jQuery wasn't referenced in the question (either explicitly with the tags or implicitly in the posted code or question), so you should probably focus on the non-jQuery approach, whether JavaScript or CSS.

Comment: i can't get the first children of each row, as i say, this tables will be generated dynamically, if i get the first children the td that is alone will be return too.
i have updated the code of the table in the quest

Comment: Hi,
you could just make an if-else condition with on the count of the children for each row and only apply new styles when the count of the td's is greater than one.